# Auto-hideable ActionBar and ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I'm using native ActionBar and ShareActionProvider.

There is a code in my activity that hides ActionBar in four seconds:

```
Handler hideUIHandler = new Handler();
hideUIHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
  public void run() { 
    getActionBar().hide();
  } 
}, 4000);
```

Unfortunately `hideUIHandler` hides ActionBar even when I clicked the "Share" item to see menu providing by ShareActionProvider.

I don't want to hide ActionBar in that case. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [`Activity.onMenuOpened`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onMenuOpened%28int,%20android.view.Menu%29) and [`Activity.onPanelClosed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPanelClosed%28int,%20android.view.Menu%29) to determine when the overflow menu or other sub-menus are showing, such as the [`ShareActionProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html). Here's an example:

```
/** True if an options menu has been opened, false otherwise */
private boolean mMenuOpened;

@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    mMenuOpened = true;
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}

@Override
public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
    mMenuOpened = false;
}
```

**Alternatively**

`ActivityChooserView` has a way to check [ActivityChooserView.isShowingPopup](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ActivityChooserView.java#L412), but you'll have to subclass `ShareActionProvider` and invoke it via reflection because the `ActivityChooserView` class is hidden.

Here's an example:

**AccessibleShareActionProvider**

```
/**
 * A subclass of {@link ShareActionProvider} that uses reflection to invoke
 * <p>
 * <code>android.widget.ActivityChooserView.isShowingPopup</code>
 * <p>
 */
public class AccessibleShareActionProvider extends ShareActionProvider {

    /** The action view created for {@link ShareActionProvider} */
    private View mActivityChooserView;

    /**
     * Constructor for <code>AccessibleShareActionProvider</code>
     * 
     * @param context The {@link Context} to use
     */
    public AccessibleShareActionProvider(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateActionView(MenuItem forItem) {
        mActivityChooserView = super.onCreateActionView(forItem);
        return mActivityChooserView;
    }

    /**
     * @return True if showing, false if already dismissed
     */
    public boolean isShowingPopup() {
        try {
            final Class<?> acv = Class.forName("android.widget.ActivityChooserView");
            final Method isShowingPopup = acv.getMethod("isShowingPopup", new Class[] {});
            return (boolean) isShowingPopup.invoke(mActivityChooserView, new Object[] {});
        } catch (final Exception ignored) {
            // Nothing to do
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Your `MenuItem`**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="your_path_to.AccessibleShareActionProvider"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/share"/>
```

**In your `Activity`**

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private AccessibleShareActionProvider mShareProvider;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...
    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    mShareProvider = (AccessibleShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    ...
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private final Runnable mHideActionBar = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // If the ShareActionProvider is showing, delay for 4 seconds
        if (mShareProvider.isShowingPopup()) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mHideActionBar, 4000);
            return;
        }
        getActionBar().hide();
    }

};
```